# jQuery val() with removing URL path

Tags: jquery, forms, anchor

I have a simple script to set a value for an input field.

```
jQuery(document).on('click','#getit', function() {
  jQuery("#getitout").val(api.get_video_link());
});
```

The api.get_video_link() returns this URL with an anchor:

`domain.com/post_type/post_name/#anchor`

How can I remove the url path and set only the anchor as value for my input field?

The input field value should be `#anchor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use regex:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','#getit', function() {
  let url = api.get_video_link();
  jQuery("#getitout").val(url.match(/.*?(\#.+$)/)[1]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have to say I'm on the beginning of my java journey and regex is something I tried to avoid until now  thanks again!